# Popover not disabling on Window Load

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a popover which when the window is loading it does not grey out. I fixed the z-index and made it lower then the load window but it did not work. Here is the code

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 caption">
                                <div class="caption bg-warning">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">
                                        €50 Playable for €40 Cash  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <a tabindex="98" id="redeem-popover" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center  " role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="
                                            <div class='btn-group-vertical'>
                                                    <a id='redeem-popover-10' class='btn btn-primary btn-default btn-lg text-center' role='button' onclick='PrintTicket(10,98, 5125, 3);'>PRINT 3</a>

                                                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                                <a id='redeem-popover-1' class='btn btn-primary btn-default btn-lg text-center' role='button' onclick='PrintTicket(10,98, 5125, 1);'>PRINT 1</a>
                                            </div>
                                            " data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover865249">  COLLECT YOUR VOUCHER <span class="badge">3</span>
                                        </a><div class="popover fade top in" role="tooltip" id="popover865249" style="top: -48.8px; left: 97.0563px; display: block;"><div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div><h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3><div class="popover-content">
                                            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                                                    <a id="redeem-popover-10" class="btn btn-primary btn-default btn-lg text-center" role="button" onclick="PrintTicket(10,98, 5125, 3);">PRINT 3</a>

                                                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                                <a id="redeem-popover-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-default btn-lg text-center" role="button" onclick="PrintTicket(10,98, 5125, 1);">PRINT 1</a>
                                            </div>
                                            </div></div>
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```